# Understanding asoundrc and hdmi output

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi, alsa

I am running nixos on a lenovo x220t. When it starts it finds the analog speakers and shows only them in alsamixer (or pavucontrol). However, when connected to an hdmi monitor/tv I can play sound through the speakers, e.g. by `speaker-test -c 2 -D hw:0,3`.

With a little trolling around the internet I came to this script,

```
pcm.!default{
type plug
slave.pcm "hdmivol"
}

pcm.hdmi-playback{
type hw
card 0
device 3
}

pcm.hdmivol{
type softvol
slave.pcm "hdmi-playback"
control {
    name "Master"
    card 0
 }
}
```

which if called `~/.asoundrc` will run sound through my hdmi tv/monitor. But to switch pack to my laptop I have to rename the script and logout and log back in.

Obviously things work, but I don't understand:
1. Why can I see and use all the devices directly, (e.g. with the speaker test) but alsamixer and pulseaudio don't "see" them?
2. Can someone provide some insight into the structure of the asoundrc. I did not make much headway with the manual, and I am not clear on why this script has three versions of the device referring to one another. And I suspect there is a way to specify an alias for hw:0,0 and hw:0,3 that would let me toggle them without having to logout and log in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the contents of `/proc/asound/cards`? What cards can be selected in alsamixer with F6?

Comment: 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf2520000 irq 25
   29 [ThinkPadEC     ]: ThinkPad EC - ThinkPad Console Audio Control
                      ThinkPad Console Audio Control at EC reg 0x30, fw unknown    These were also the two options in alsamixer before I installed pulseaudio (which didn't help).

Comment: `alsamixer` shows only mixer *controls*; the digital output typcially has no volume control. Doesn't PulseAudio see the digital output?

Comment: No. It did not. I could manually add a sink, but there was still no sound coming out through the tv/monitor. Happy to provide any other system clarifying details. Thanks for your interest.